# Can I add 100a subpanel to detached lean-to 25ft from main panel. Use nr2 URD buried up leg to disconnect & then THHN over to indoor garage subpanel

Tags: wiring

What is the approved method for attaching a JB to the metal leg of a lean-to?

This is a manufactured metal building on concrete, basically a single car garage sized shop with a 10ft overhang in the front and a 9ft lean-to on the side. The main panel is located at the house, 20 feet away. A JB would make the pull much easier I think. There will be two grounding rods for the subpanel.

I haven't determined the cabling choice, direct burial or conduit, aluminum cable being most cost effective.

Comment: You have taken the [tour] so you should know now that asking multiple questions in one question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Is the lean-to a building?  Structural I ask as what I call a lean-2 would not qualify. Your panel location can be outside on a pole or post if listed (NEMA3R) or it can be inside, a metal member is usually connected with through bolts and compression lugs if you are grounding the frame. Lots of info needed before any questions can be answered.

Comment: By 50A wire I hope you mean #6 aluminum.  Using copper would be nuts, it's too expensive.  Aluminum is fine at large sizes, but a few people distrust #6... fine then, use #2, it is universally accepted and still cheap.  And 90A. The disconnect should be part of the subpanel, just use a main breaker sub. There is no need for the disconnect to be outside.

Comment: Please [edit] this down to fewer questions. It will bump to the top and be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

A j box can be mounted to the structure of your building.

2 screws are the minimum with larger boxes requiring 3 or 4.

Now where a specific type of screw may be required if using a metal J-box you can use sheet metal screws for lightweight metal studs or self tapping if not bonding the box at this point (if the structure is Not bonded quick and dirty screws are ok)

If you are bonding or using the connection from the box to the metal structure a self forming screw or through bolts are required.

A self forming screw has machine screw threads, 2 threads are required to be in contact (sheet metal type self tapping only 1 thread will be in contact) code is specific on 2 threads in contact and this usually requires 32 threads per inch for bonding in these cases. See 250.8 for 2 threads requirement

Comment: Thanks for comments.   I was thinking it best to add a JB for cable pull.  Would it also be a cost saving to switch (at the JB) over from direct burial cabling to another, like MC ?

Comment: Cary it is a better way to go in many cases but the connection to the building is still a concern as you will be using large conductors see table for the wire size to cubic inches and make sure to get a large enough box as #6 is 5 cubic inches per conductor, table 314.16.b and if a metal box the splice Shall be bonded to the box, I did not say that stuff just to say it it is a place inspectors regularly verify code is being followed , clamp’s and their size the current carrying conductors and grounds all add up.